# Qt how to extract hyperlink into a variable

Tags: string, qt, text, hyperlink

Take this as an example:

```
QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("test"), tr("click <a href='http://example.com'>mock</a>"));
```

What I want is to extract "http://example.com" to a variable so I can reuse it in other messagebox. Plus I can easily manage this variable rather than change all strings if I need to change it.

Comment: Please be more clear. You want that to keep that in memory? If not QString than QUrl then. Or what?

Comment: Extract url to a constant string, then I can use it somewhere else, if I want to change the url, I only need to change 1 place. What do you mean by "If not QString than QUrl then."

Comment: Still not clear. Please provide your code where you have the problem.

Comment: how do I cancel the html format in my text, I pasted the code I used, but it has html hyperlink and it doesn't show properly

Comment: Could you provide more clarity about the input and where it's coming from?  For example is it any arbitrary HTML, is it well-formed XHTML, etc?

Comment: It's a html hyperlink in a messagebox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is similar but not exact question answered: [How to use regex to replace URLs with an HTML link in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321256/how-to-use-regex-to-replace-urls-with-an-html-link-in-qt) I took the regex pattern from that page and applied to your case:

```
QString urlStr = "<a href='http://example.com'>mock</a>";
QRegExp rx("((?:https?|ftp)://\\S+)");
int pos = rx.indexIn(urlStr, 0);
if (-1 != pos)
{
    QString cap = rx.cap(0);
    cap = cap.left(cap.indexOf('\''));
    qDebug() << cap; // see the result
}
```

The pattern can be improved, of course.